# FlowLayoutPanel remove control when click on it c#

Tags: c#, controls

Currently I have a flowlayoutpanel named FlowPending and an UserControl named ItemDetail, Flowpending generates ItemDetail from the DataTable results, the code of the flowlayoutpanel is here:

```
var items = Details.GetItemDetail(logNo, date);
    foreach (DataRow item in items.Rows)
    {
        var itemDisplay = new UserControls.ItemDetail();
        itemDisplay.itemName = item["ItemName"].ToString();
        itemDisplay.qty = item["Qty"].ToString();
        itemDisplay.container = item["Containers"].ToString();
        FlowPending.Controls.Add(itemDisplay);
    }
```

Now what I want to do is that when I click on any of the ItemDetail inside the FlowPending, the particular ItemDetail will be removed, this is what I have tried, but apparently it does not work:

```
public void removeControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FlowPending.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    public void test()
    {
        foreach (Control c in FlowPending.Controls)
        {
            c.MouseClick += removeControl;
        }
    }
```

I have placed the test() function in the form_load method FYI

## Update:

Hi, guys, I have figured out how to do it, just 3 simple lines:

```
Control c = this.Parent;
        if (c.Name.Equals("yourcontrolname"))
        {
            c.Controls.Remove(this);
```

I m not sure if anyone gonna read this, but just for the sake of people who may need it in the future, I just post the code here :)

Comment: try debugging your code. check if your application enters in removecontrol event handler or not.

Comment: @jadavparesh06 yes, it enters, but this method does not seem working though.

Comment: It does *something*, just not remove the control that was clicked.  Use FlowPending.Controls.Remove((Control)sender);

Comment: hi @HansPassant, yes I tried the method mentioned above, it worked! Thank you so much